# Can't create table in laravel "General error: 1 table has more than one primary key"

Tags: sql, laravel

When using the following command `php artisan migrate` it returns the following error:

> General error: 1 table - has more than one primary key

I have tried forcing primary key using

```
$table->primary('id');
```

**Note:** the ID being referenced in the other table is also of data type bigIncrements

```
Schema::create('stuff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('class'); 
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->bigIncrements('owner');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->bigIncrements('teacher');
        $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('othertable');
        $table->foreign('teacher')->references('id')->on('othertable');
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know laravel, but `bigIncrements` sounds like it would create a primary key - auto incrementing fields are usually PKs.

Comment: why do you create 3 bigIncrements? change it to integer field

Comment: See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make owner and teacher `bigInteger` instead

```
Schema::create('stuff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('class'); 
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->bigInteger('owner')->unsigned();
        $table->float('price');
        $table->bigInteger('teacher')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('othertable');
        $table->foreign('teacher')->references('id')->on('othertable');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you use `bigIncrements` instead of integer

`bigIncrements` create primary key

if `owners` and `teachers` tables has `bigIncrements` id column so replace migration codes with:

```
Schema::create('stuff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('class'); 
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('teacher');
        $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('othertable');
        $table->foreign('teacher')->references('id')->on('othertable');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously **bigIncrements** datatype in Laravel is going to make that field **primary key**. In this case, you are having three primary keys which are **Id, Owner and Teacher** Fields.
To remove the last two from being primary keys add the following code in your migration file.

```
Schema::table('stuff', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('owner');
    $table->dropPrimary('teacher');
});
```

Also, If these two fields (owner, teacher) are reference fields, I guess you don't need to give them a datatype of bigIncrements. Changing them to unsignedBigInteger can be a better choice.